# Will a Barclaycard Visa help me in building up credit score?

Tags: united-states, loans, credit-score

Apple has got finance option for its products through Barclaycard Visa as pointed out [here](https://www.barclaycardus.com/apply/Landing.action?campaignId=2217&cellNumber=1&channel=4&referrerid=GGLPS0716&gclid=CLmg8MHXvc8CFcq8fgodd2ENlA) and [here](http://www.apple.com/shop/browse/finance/instant_credit). Will the monthly repayment to the card help me building credit score?

If the answer to the question above is "Yes"; since Barclaycard allows interest free repayment till 18 months from the date of purchase, should I pay the debt back in shorter (e.g. 6 months) or longer (<= 18 months) term to improve my credit score the most?

Comment: I'm not convinced a single transaction, however you repay it, will have a great deal of positive effect on your score.

Comment: But, it's a hefty amount as compared to shopping groceries.

Answer (score 1):

Payment history is probably the most significant contributor to your credit score.  Having a solid history of making, at least the minimum, payments on time will have a positive impact on your credit score.  Whether or not this specific transaction means anything to that equation is up for debate.

If you have no credit lines now and 0% for 18 months on a computer makes sense to you, then yes, making this purchase this way and paying on time will have a positive impact on your credit score.  Paying interest doesn't help your credit score.  Repay this computer before the 18 month period ends, then be sure to pay your balance in full every month thereafter.

Comment: I couldn't understand `"Repay this computer before the 18 month period ends, then be sure to pay your balance in full every month thereafter"`

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock do not pay any interest.  It does not help you to pay interest.  If you're getting 18 months of 0% interest, pay off your balance before the 18 month period ends, then if you charge anything new, pay it off every month.  Paying interest is of absolutely no benefit to you.